# Simultaneously editing a sqlite table and outputting an element of it

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite table that I want to update a row of. I also want to select that row and send the elements of it to the program that is updating it.

Currently I am doing that via two separate queries.

```
c.execute("""UPDATE Table1 SET Col1=(?)  
                WHERE Col2=(?) AND Col3=(?)
                """, (var1, var2, var3,))

c.execute("""SELECT * from Table1 
             WHERE Col1=(?) AND Col2=(?) AND Col3=(?)
          """,(var1, var2, var3,))

items       = c.fetchall()
```

However that means that SQLite has to search through the table twice, which is much slower. Is it possible to update and then select the row with a single query?

Comment: In the next version of SQLite 3.35.0 (2021-03-30) there will be available a RETURNING clause: https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_returning.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have such a feature (incidentially, MS SQL has with it's `MERGE INTO`, but that's not helpful here).

What you are doing is technically the way to go. First `UPDATE`, then `SELECT`.

You are correct that the database engine then has to find the relevant row(s) twice. But this  here  is a case of pre-optimization. Is having SQLite finding the relevant row(s) twice an issue? Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. It all depends on the current situation.

If it *is* an issue, then it is appropriate to find a solution. In this case with Python and SQLite, I do not believe there is a viable solution to avoid having the database engine finding the relevant row(s) twice (again, Entity Framework in C# can do some tricks such as storing the data locally, and again, doesn't help here).

Finding and writing rows in a database is what databases does best. But there are ways of helping, so the database does not have to do a full table-scan to find the relevant row(s).

Introducing *Indexes*: You simply tell the database which columns you intend to search through often enough to warrant that it compiles an index of which rows has which values for that column. In your case, create an index on columns `Col1`, and a combined column on `Col2` and `Col3`. You could also consider using primary keys, which is a unique value for each row - efficiently the primary lookup value for a row.

Read e.g. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/